# Converting a bash command output into JSON and serving it over http on the fly

Tags: json, bash, command-line, graph, statistics

I want to convert the output of `ifstat` command into JSON and serve it over http on the fly to be used for a javascript graph app. Are there any lightweight -- sed or awk -- command-line solutions which I can use? I do not want to store JSON output on the disk and it would be good if the web-server was a small lightweight command line tool into which I can pipe JSON output.

EDIT 1:

[This](http://smoothiecharts.org/) is the live streaming chart library which will use the data. I'm not keen on a specific web server; any webserver that does the job would be fine.

Comment: there are too many ways for doing it. Please define better who are going to consume the output generated by your bash/sed/awk stream data, which is the HTTP server and how do you plan to fetch data asynchronously from the webserver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I have tried.

#### Terminal #1

```
ifstat -n | awk 'NR>2{print systime(),$0; fflush()}' | tee ifstat.log
```

#### Terminal #2

```
while :
do
{ 
    echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
    echo -e "Content-Type: application/json\n"
    tail -n1 ifstat.log | awk '{ printf("{\"time\":%s, \"in\":%s, \"out\":%s}\n", $1, $2, $3) }'
} | nc -l 8000
done
```

#### firefox

open: http://localhost:8000

```
{"time":1332052321, "in":1.24, "out":2.62}
```

I know little about `JSON`. Maybe the output is invalid. You should rewrite the `awk` command.

Comment: Its almost what I was looking for. When firefox makes a GET request can I get a one line reply like this: `{"in":1.11, "out":2.79}`

Comment: try: `printf("\"in%s\":%s, \"out%s\":%s,\n", NR, $1, NR, $2)`

Comment: It didn't work. The browser should show just one line. The above script diplays 10 lines at a time.

Comment: try `tail -n 1 ifstat.log` to get only one item

Comment: If you can post your desired output, it will be easier for me to write the script.

Comment: I was able to get the desired output which is: `{"time":1332051642,"in":0.13,"out":0.22}`. For time I'm using sustime() function.

Comment: I would be good If the script can be made to work from just one terminal.